# Trying to do a find/replace with wildcard

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through all text files in a folder, open each, do a find/replace, save each, and close each.  My code looks like this.

```
Sub FindAndReplaceText()

 Dim FileName As String
 Dim FolderPath As String
 Dim FSO As Object
 Dim I As Integer
 Dim SearchForWords As Variant
 Dim SubstituteWords As Variant
 Dim Text As String
 Dim TextFile As Object

  'Change these arrays to word you want to find and replace
  SearchForWords = Array("  steps:" & "*" & "        fields:")
  SubstituteWords = Array("  global" & vbCrLf & "    global:" & vbCrLf & "      schema_def:" & vbCrLf & "        fields:")

  'Change the folder path to where your text files are.
  ' look for all lines with: '      - .*Pricing_RealEstate' & '*'
   FolderPath = "C:\path_here\"

     Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

     FolderPath = IIf(Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\", FolderPath & "\", FolderPath)
     FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "\*.txt")

     Do While FileName <> ""
       FileSpec = FolderPath & FileName
        'Read all the file's text into a string variable.
         Set TextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileSpec, 1, False)
           Text = TextFile.ReadAll
         TextFile.Close

        'Scan the string for words to replace and write the string back to the file.
         Set TextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileSpec, 2, False)
           For I = 0 To UBound(SearchForWords)
           Debug.Print Text
             Replace Text, SearchForWords(I), SubstituteWords(I)
           Debug.Print Text
           Next I
         TextFile.Write Text
         TextFile.Close
       FileName = Dir()
     Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: if these are text files, why not use a command line with Vi or grep for example - depending on the system...

Comment: Would help to show the "after" for the lines you want to alter.  Might want to set up a separate folder to write out the "fixed" files, leaving the originals untouched, otherwise it's tricky to track what changes were made, and if you make a mistake you can just fix your code and re-run it.

Comment: I just edited my original post.  I added some screen shots, and a little more explanation.  I think, if there is an easy way to account for line breaks, this shouldn't be too complex.  It just seems like the line breaks are throwing things off.

Comment: Here's an ugly way you could do this but it'd require you to loop each file twice - on the first run you get the line number for each start `steps:` and the line number for each end `fields:`, then the second pass you replace/cut/(something, idk all the features `fso` has for text files) the lines between those line numbers with your intended replacement. It's real ugly but should work assuming all start keywords have an end keyword

Comment: Yeah, all starts have ends.  Did you post some sample code?  I didn't see anything 'ugly'.  I don't care if it's ugly or beautiful, I just want to get something working here.  Thanks.

Comment: I posted code right when this was posted but I didnt understand the question correctly at that point. Instead of using `Text.ReadAll` I'd use [`Text.ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/textstream-object) for my approach

Comment: OP tries to use wild cards with no success: suppose wrong use of range related `.Replace` - there are no cell values, only string values; VBA function replace on the other hand doesn't support wild cards as in OP. I'd recommend to use regular expressions instead (many examples at SO :-). Take into account, too that different operating systems  (UNIX, mac) could define other new line characters, e.g. only a chr(10) line feed instead of chr(13) + chr(10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is tried and working with the sample data:

```
Sub FindAndReplaceText2()
 Dim FileName, FileName2 As String
 Dim FolderPath, FolderPath2 As String
 Dim FileSpec, FileSpec2 As String
 Dim FSO As Object
 Dim SearchForWords As String
 Dim SubstituteWords As String
 Dim Text As String
 Dim TextFile As Object

  'Change these arrays to word you want to find and replace
  SearchForWords = "  steps:" & "*" & "        fields:"
  SubstituteWords = "  global" & vbCrLf & "    global:" & vbCrLf & "      schema_def:" & vbCrLf & "        fields:"
 
  
  'Change the folder path to where your text files are.
  ' look for all lines with: '      - .*Pricing_RealEstate' & '*'
   FolderPath = "C:\users\user\Desktop\New Folder\"
   FolderPath2 = "C:\users\user\Desktop\New Folder2\"
   Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "\*.txt")

     Do While FileName <> ""
       FileSpec = FolderPath & FileName
       FileSpec2 = FolderPath2 & FileName
       
        'Read all the file's text into a string variable.
         Set TextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileSpec, 1, False)
         Text = TextFile.ReadAll
         TextFile.Close
         'SrchReplText Now  work for single wildcard only
         Text = SrchReplText(Text, SearchForWords, SubstituteWords)
        'Scan the string for words to replace and write the string back to the file.
         Set TextFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(FileSpec2, 2, False)
         TextFile.Write Text
         TextFile.Close
     FileName = Dir()
     Loop
End Sub

Private Function SrchReplText(Txt As String, SrcTxt As String, RplTxt As String) As Variant
'Now for single wildcard only using single loop
Dim Wordx, Word3 As Variant
Dim I, I2 As Long
SrchReplText = Txt
Wordx = Split(SrcTxt, "*")
If UBound(Wordx) > 1 Then Exit Function
If UBound(Wordx) = 1 Then
Do
  Found = False
  I = InStr(1, SrchReplText, Wordx(0))
  If I > 0 Then I2 = InStr(I, SrchReplText, Wordx(1))
     If I > 0 And I2 > 0 Then
     Found = True
     Word3 = Mid(SrchReplText, I, I2 - I + Len(Wordx(1)))
     SrchReplText = Replace(SrchReplText, Word3, RplTxt, 1, 1)
     End If
Loop While Found
Else
SrchReplText = Replace(SrchReplText, SrcTxt, RplTxt, 1, 1)
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Just a side note to your declarations: "If you don't specify a data type or object type [..]" as e.g. in `Dim I, I2 As Long`, the *[first]* variable `I` "is Variant by default " - c.f. [MS Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dim-statement)

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Thanks if it is useful it made my day.. And  @T.M. appreciate  for reminding..I will keep a watch on it.